# QueryDSL Order by calculated field

Tags: java, querydsl

In our application we use querydsl to fetch entities and transform them to a presentation object.
This presentation object has field called `active`. This is decided by whether a certain date of the entity is before today (active = false) or after today (active = true). All goes well doing this. The problem is when trying to order by that expression (`QEntity.someDate > today`). Which makes hibernate throw this error:

```java
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: > near line 3, column 40 [select object.someField as someAlias, (object.someDate > ?1) as active, object as objectAlias
from com.example.Object object
order by object.someDate > ?1 asc]
```

I create the `OrderSpecifier` as follows:

```java
    @Override
    public OrderSpecifier<?> getOrderByClause(SortKey sortKey) {
        BooleanExpression expression = getBooleanPath(); // This is the expression: (object.someDate > ?1)
        if (sortKey.getSortOrder() == ESortOrder.ASCENDING) {
            return new OrderSpecifier(Order.ASC, expression);
        }
        return new OrderSpecifier(Order.DESC, expression);
    }
```

I also tried it like this:

```java
    @Override
    public OrderSpecifier<?> getOrderByClause(SortKey sortKey) {
        BooleanExpression expression = getBooleanPath();
        if (sortKey.getSortOrder() == ESortOrder.ASCENDING) {
            return new CaseBuilder().when(expression.isFalse()).then(1).otherwise(2).asc();
        }
        return new CaseBuilder().when(expression.isTrue()).then(1).otherwise(2).desc();
    }
```

Which results in a similar error:

```java
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: > near line 3, column 40 [select object.someField as someAlias, (object.someDate > ?1) as active, object as objectAlias
from com.example.Object object
order by case when (object.someDate > ?1 = ?2) then ?3 else 2 end asc]
```

And finally like this:

```java
    @Override
    public OrderSpecifier<?> getOrderByClause(SortKey sortKey) {
        BooleanExpression expression = getBooleanPath();
        if (sortKey.getSortOrder() == ESortOrder.ASCENDING) {
            return new CaseBuilder().when(expression.eq(true)).then(1).otherwise(2).asc();
        }
        return new CaseBuilder().when(expression.eq(true)).then(1).otherwise(2).desc();
    }
```

Which throws the same error as the previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by creating the order clause like this:

```java
    @Override
    public OrderSpecifier<?> getOrderByClause(SortKey sortKey) {
        BooleanPath path = getBooleanPath();
        if (sortKey.getSortOrder() == ESortOrder.ASCENDING) {
            return path.asc();
        }
        return path.desc();
    }

    private BooleanPath getBooleanPath() {
        return Expressions.booleanPath(getFieldName());
    }
```

Where field name is the alias as string, in our case `"active"`.